# How to create a transaction for order and orders details tables (n registries)?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The issue is that I have to record a "transaction" is a voucher header (order table) and details (order details table) .. say as an invoice .. A table header and items (DETAIL) the thing is that a header record you are 1 or more items in the table details.

The question: Is there a way to pass N records (sets of parameters)

EDIT. I plan to write this transacction since SQL SERVER and not in the application cliente (STORE PROCEDURE)

Comment: This can certainly be done, but how depends on what data access method you use. Is this using pure `SqlCommand` or something like linq-to-sql?

Comment: No, I'm using datasets in my client application. And I'm only invoke the stored procedure name

Comment: In SQL 2008 / .Net you can just dump the data table into SQL; see this how to http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/ado/10/10138579/passing-dataset-to-stored-procedure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the transaction on your connection from the client (e.g. C# application), not in the database. Pseudo-code:

- open connection
- open transaction
- store order data
- for item = 1 .. n

  - store order item
- commit transaction
- close connection

Here's an example from Microsoft, modified slightly to illustrate your particular case:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=VS.100).aspx

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    // Start a local transaction.
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();

    // Enlist a command in the current transaction.
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = sqlTran;

    try
    {
        // Execute two separate commands.
        command.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO Order ...";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

//NOTE: your command should probably return the ID of the new order, so you can pass it to the OrderItem inserts below; in that case you may want to use command.ExecuteScalar() or command.ExecuteReader() to return the ID; In the simplest scenario you could execute another command with "SELECT @@SCOPE_IDENTITY()" as the text, but it's much better to write a stored procedure to handle your insert (and return the ID)

```
        foreach (var item in order.Items)
        {
           command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OrderItem ... ";
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        // Commit the transaction.
        sqlTran.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception if the transaction fails to commit.
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        try
        {
            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            sqlTran.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception exRollback)
        {
            // Throws an InvalidOperationException if the connection 
            // is closed or the transaction has already been rolled 
            // back on the server.
            Console.WriteLine(exRollback.Message);
        }
    }
}
```